# Regex AND search inside block which enclosed by something delimiter

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to regex AND search `(?=)(?=)` inside block which enclosed by something delimiter such as `#`

In following sample regex, what I expected is, `cat` to `ugly` matches to the pattern inside `# cat B` to before `# cat C`.
But the regex match to nothing.

regex

```
^#(?=[\s\S]*(cat))(?=[\s\S]*(ugly))^#
```

text

```
# cat A

the cat is
very cute.

# cat B

the cat is
very ugly.

# cat C

the cat is
very good.

#
```

You can test the regex on [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/4csov)

Comment: The second `^` is going to break your regex. Use `\n` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern `^#(?=[\s\S]*(cat))(?=[\s\S]*(ugly))^#` you use match a `#` from the start of the string `^#`, followed by 2 positive lookaheads and then again match `^#`. That is why you don't get a match.

To get a more exact match, you could start the pattern with `^# cat B`

If you want to use lookaheads, you might use 2 capturing groups in the positive lookahead. If you want to search for cat and ugly as whole words you might use word boundaries `\b`.

The `(?s)` is a modifier that enables the dot matching a newline for which you might also use `/s` as a flag instead.

```
(?s)(?=^# cat B.*?(cat).*?(ugly).*?^# cat C
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2xaOk/2)

But it might be easier to not use the lookahead and match instead:

```
(?s)^# cat B.*?(cat).*?(ugly).*?^# cat C$
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/UZOQa)

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/dyyCA8/1) might help you to design/match your target words by bounding them using <kbd>\n</kbd>.

```
((.+)(cat)(.+))\n((.+)(ugly)(.+))
```

Just to be simple, it creates four groups for each target keywords:  and <kbd>ugly</kbd>, where your target keywords can be called using <kbd>$3</kbd> and <kbd>$7</kbd>:

[image]

You could additionally bound it with start <kbd>^</kbd> and end <kbd>$</kbd>, if you wish.

> This expression only works when your target keywords are in the middle of both lines.